# MS SQL Graph Database Node and Edge Table design guidance Require

Tags: sql-server, sql-graph

I am creating one application, which requires dynamic store data in a Graph Table (using Nodes and Edges).

Each Table contains one Product information.

| Details | Fix or Dynamic | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Fix | Require for all products |
| Parts | Dynamic | Require parts is based on products. |
| Measue | Dynamic | Mainly use for find profit and other calculations e.g **Product 2** contains *Discount* and **Product 3** contains *Discount + Tax* |

**Requiremens**

- Need to Store all information in MS SQL Graph Database
- Need to Add Extra Property against Measure like User Name and Date Created etc.

Note: This extra Property in the feature can be added more details like Date Updated etc.

Current Approach:
Currently, we are storing all information in JSON format in SQL server for save and Get.

```json
{
      "Product Name":"Bike With 1 Part",
      "Part 1":"Steel",
      "Sell":"15",
      "Cost":"9",
      "Profit":"4"
},

 {
      "Product Name":"Bike With 2 Part",
      "Part 1":"Plastic",
      "Part 2":"Steel",
      "Sell":"12",
      "Cost":"9",
      "Discount":"2",
      "Profit":"1"
   },
   {
      "Product Name":"Bike With 3 Part",
      "Part 1":"Plastic",
      "Part 2":"Steel",
      "Part 2":"Copper",
      "Sell":"15",
      "Cost":"9",
      "Discount":"2",
      "Tax":"1",
      "Profit":"3"
  },
```

Problem statement :

1. Json Format is not fixed as the Part number and measure count can be up and down
2. Discount, Tax , Part Number are dynamic (It May be required for a product or not)
3. If require information like "Product -> Part 1 -> Profit" that is not possible using JSON Format.

**Final Requirement:**
Create a Graph Node and Edge Tables.

1. Instead of Json format need to store all information in MS SQL Graph DB. With node and Edge tables.  So Require help on creating a Node and Edge table design.

Note:Fetching of Data can be by Product Name ,Part Number , Profit, etc. using Graph Query Match query.

[Product Information in Relational DB Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSvpX.png)

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking here? You give some problem statements, but you don't tell us what, specifically, is the question you are asking.

Comment: Added Final Requirement section for more detail requirement.

Comment: "need help" isn't an answerable question: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983). What is it you need help with specifically? What have you tried so far? Why isn't it working?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.